# Get all brands with freebase query editor but it return 100

Tags: google-api, freebase

I ran that [query](http://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=[%7B%22id%22:null,%22name%22:null,%22type%22:%22/business/brand%22%7D]) . it returns 103 result in JSON format. but overall 8,677 brands are stored in freebase. can i get all brands in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't get precisely 100?  That's the default limit for queries.

You should read about MQL cursors: https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview#querying-with-cursor-paging-results